# Opencv, DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I installed OpenCV to Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to fallow tutorials at opencv website. I got an error while running this code. I'm using eclipse 
to run the code. I'm getting this error while building project. 
I added, opencv_core, opencv_highgui,opencv_imgcodecs libraries to g++ linker.

```
Error message: 

//usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [optest01] Error 1
```

Code :

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

/// Global variables

Mat src, src_gray;
Mat dst, detected_edges;

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load an image
  src = imread( "/images/Lenna.jpg" );

  if( !src.data )
  { return -1; }

  /// Create a matrix of the same type and size as src (for dst)
  dst.create( src.size(), src.type() );

  /// Convert the image to grayscale
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Have you linked `opencv_imgproc`?

Comment: @Miki, thank you for the answer it works. how can i know that which libraries to link at tutorials it is not writing

Comment: 1) add one by one according to the error message until it works 2) add them all in the first place 3) add the lib according to your #include 4) once you know how OpenCV works, you'll know what to link

Comment: @Miki You should post your comment as the answer to this question so seleucia can accept it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your error code:

> //usr/local/lib/**libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0**: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

is telling you that you haven't linked `opencv_imgproc`.
Just link the required library:

```
-lopencv_imgproc
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem `DSO missing from command line` and adding the `-L/usr/local/lib`in front solved the problem for me i.e. `g++ source_code.cpp -o output_name -L/usr/local/lib <dependent libraries e.g. -lopencv_highgui>`